# How to update list contents

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two `list`

```py
A = [
    {'name':'Tom', 'country':'American', 'birthday': '2001'},
    {'name':'Tim', 'country':'India'},
    {'name':'Peter', 'country':'China'},
]
B = [
    {'name':'Tom', 'country':'China', 'birthday': '...', 'dream': '...'},
]
```

We think the `list A` was a new list and the `list B` was the old list. I have some problems with how to write a code to upgrade the old list.
The result will be：

```
[{'name': 'Tom', 'country': 'China', 'birthday': '2001', 'dream': '...'},
 {'name': 'Tim', 'country': 'India'},
 {'name': 'Peter', 'country': 'China'}]
```

I don't have any idea about this.

Comment: SO you want to update only country? or all keys? Is birthday changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to update all keys, using "name" as merging key.

You can build a dictionary of `B` using the name as key, then loop over `A` to [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) each dictionary:

```
B_dict = {d['name']: d for d in B if 'name' in d}

for d in A:
    if 'name' in d:
        d.update(B_dict.get(d['name'], {}))
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Tom', 'country': 'China', 'birthday': '...', 'dream': '...'},
 {'name': 'Tim', 'country': 'India'},
 {'name': 'Peter', 'country': 'China'}]
```

---

Just in case `...` have a special meaning and you only want to add them if there is not already a non `...` value, you can tweak the above approach to only pass the `key:...` for which there is not already an existing valid value:

```
B_dict = {d['name']: d for d in B if 'name' in d}
for d in A:
    if 'name' in d:
        d.update({k: v for k,v in B_dict.get(d['name'], {}).items()
                  if v != '...' or k not in d})
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Tom', 'country': 'China', 'birthday': '2001', 'dream': '...'},
 {'name': 'Tim', 'country': 'India'},
 {'name': 'Peter', 'country': 'China'}]
```

Comment: @Ohhhhh do the `...` have a special meaning? or was it just a placeholder? I added an alternative if this is the case